# Unzip creating a directory

Tags: python, linux, bash, compression, unzip

`unzip -o my_file_name.esb.zip`

Results in

```
Archive:  my_file_name.esb.zip
  inflating: my_file_name.esb  
checkdir error:  my_file_name.esb exists but is not directory
                 unable to process my_file_name.esb/.
```

Only for this specific file. After executing the command, `ls` reveals that `my_file_name.esb` is extracted, but turned into an empty directory. It is also a binary file, which is the sort of file I expected.

Repeating the command after the file is extracted sometimes yields:

```
Archive: my_file_name.esb.zip
error: cannot delete old my_file_name.esb
       Is a directory
```

I'm rather confused why this file acts both as a file and a directory. It causes an error in the Python script that's running unzip, preventing it from continuing.

In Python:

```
from sh import gunzip
unzip('-o',myfile)
```

Where `myfile` is the path to the .zip archive.

Python stops here:

```
sh.py(187):         if self.stderr is None:
sh.py(190):             exc_stderr = self.stderr[:self.truncate_cap]
sh.py(191):             err_delta = len(self.stderr) - len(exc_stderr)
sh.py(192):             if err_delta:
sh.py(195):         msg = "\n\n  RAN: %r\n\n  STDOUT:\n%s\n\n  STDERR:\n%s" % \
sh.py(196):             (full_cmd, exc_stdout.decode(DEFAULT_ENCODING, "replace"),
 --- modulename: utf_8, funcname: decode
utf_8.py(16):     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
sh.py(197):              exc_stderr.decode(DEFAULT_ENCODING, "replace"))
 --- modulename: utf_8, funcname: decode
utf_8.py(16):     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
sh.py(198):         super(ErrorReturnCode, self).__init__(msg)
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/trace.py", line 819, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/trace.py", line 807, in main
    t.runctx(code, globs, globs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/trace.py", line 513, in runctx
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "importItAll.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1021, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 500, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: '/usr/bin/unzip -o ./path/to/my_file_name.esb.zip'

  STDOUT:
sh.py(1269):                 if stderr is OProc.STDOUT:
sh.py(1272):                     os.dup2(self._slave_stderr_fd, 2)
sh.py(1275):                 max_fd = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[0]
sh.py(1276):                 os.closerange(3, max_fd)
sh.py(1280):                 if self.call_args["tty_out"]:
sh.py(1281):                     tmp_fd = os.open(os.ttyname(1), os.O_RDWR)
sh.py(1282):                     os.close(tmp_fd)
sh.py(1285):                 if self.call_args["tty_out"]:
sh.py(1286):                     setwinsize(1, self.call_args["tty_size"])
 --- modulename: sh, funcname: setwinsize
sh.py(1036):     rows, cols = rows_cols
sh.py(1037):     TIOCSWINSZ = getattr(termios, 'TIOCSWINSZ', -2146929561)
sh.py(1039):  ... (365 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:
checkdir error:  my_file_name.esb exists but is not directory
                 unable to process my_file_name.esb/.
```

Any suggestions?

Using Archive manager, I found the zip file contains:

```
Name                Size          Type         Modified
my_file_name.esb    0  bytes      Folder       17 February 2016, 12:40
my_file_name.esb    581.3 MB      unknown      16 February 2016, 13:45
```

Comment: Remove the Python tag because you don't show any Python code. If you think this is a Python programming problem, add the code and the exception that is raised.

Comment: Added the Python code.

Comment: List the contents of the zip file? Perhaps it has conflicting entries or case-distinct entries and you are on a non-case-sensitive file system?

Comment: This explains it a little bit. Added the contents of the zip file above.

Comment: Yep. There's your answer. Whoever made that file is messing with you.